Apache Ignite 2.15.0 : WAL history is too short
I am using Apache Ignite (2.15.0) in .NET6 project to run Ignite cache on a single partition node. It was running fine without any issues. However, following recent Windows updates on one of the machines, the Ignite cache was affected during the system restart. When the machine rebooted, the Ignite cache also shut down and encountered some errors in the process, please find the errors that occurred during the Ignite cache shutdown.
[00:56:54,723][INFO][db-checkpoint-thread-#104][Checkpointer] Checkpoint started [checkpointId=dd4d8fed-8916-46e2-98ee-bcf93eb4bf6d, startPtr=WALPointer [idx=470, fileOff=15927777, len=50617], checkpointBeforeLockTime=4ms, checkpointLockWait=0ms, checkpointListenersExecuteTime=2ms, checkpointLockHoldTime=2ms, walCpRecordFsyncDuration=8ms, writeCheckpointEntryDuration=2ms, splitAndSortCpPagesDuration=0ms, pages=767, reason='timeout']
[00:56:54,810][INFO][db-checkpoint-thread-#104][Checkpointer] Checkpoint finished [cpId=dd4d8fed-8916-46e2-98ee-bcf93eb4bf6d, pages=767, markPos=WALPointer [idx=470, fileOff=15927777, len=50617], walSegmentsCovered=[], markDuration=12ms, pagesWrite=4ms, fsync=83ms, total=103ms]
[00:57:03,297][SEVERE][grid-nio-worker-client-listener-1-#42][ClientListenerProcessor] Failed to process selector key [ses=GridSelectorNioSessionImpl [worker=DirectNioClientWorker [super=AbstractNioClientWorker [idx=1, bytesRcvd=379299492, bytesSent=0, bytesRcvd0=489020, bytesSent0=0, select=true, super=GridWorker [name=grid-nio-worker-client-listener-1, igniteInstanceName=null, finished=false, heartbeatTs=1723577222285, hashCode=946306202, interrupted=false, runner=grid-nio-worker-client-listener-1-#42]]], writeBuf=java.nio.DirectByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=65536 cap=65536], readBuf=java.nio.DirectByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=65536 cap=65536], inRecovery=null, outRecovery=null, closeSocket=true, outboundMessagesQueueSizeMetric=o.a.i.i.processors.metric.impl.LongAdderMetric@63a61cb2, super=GridNioSessionImpl [locAddr=/127.0.0.1:10800, rmtAddr=/127.0.0.1:60301, createTime=1723038738969, closeTime=0, bytesSent=4968, bytesRcvd=1754, bytesSent0=0, bytesRcvd0=0, sndSchedTime=1723038739144, lastSndTime=1723038739144, lastRcvTime=1723038739133, readsPaused=false, filterChain=FilterChain[filters=[GridNioAsyncNotifyFilter, GridNioCodecFilter [parser=ClientListenerNioMessageParser, directMode=true], SSL filter], accepted=true, markedForClose=false]]]
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.throwConnectionReset(SocketChannelImpl.java:394)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:426)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$DirectNioClientWorker.processRead(GridNioServer.java:1351)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$AbstractNioClientWorker.processSelectedKeysOptimized(GridNioServer.java:2526)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$AbstractNioClientWorker.bodyInternal(GridNioServer.java:2281)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$AbstractNioClientWorker.body(GridNioServer.java:1910)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:125)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
[00:57:03,298][SEVERE][grid-nio-worker-client-listener-0-#41][ClientListenerProcessor] Failed to process selector key [ses=GridSelectorNioSessionImpl [worker=DirectNioClientWorker [super=AbstractNioClientWorker [idx=0, bytesRcvd=3762640641, bytesSent=0, bytesRcvd0=599030499, bytesSent0=0, select=true, super=GridWorker [name=grid-nio-worker-client-listener-0, igniteInstanceName=null, finished=false, heartbeatTs=1723577222285, hashCode=841215123, interrupted=false, runner=grid-nio-worker-client-listener-0-#41]]], writeBuf=java.nio.DirectByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=65320 cap=65536], readBuf=java.nio.DirectByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=65536 cap=65536], inRecovery=null, outRecovery=null, closeSocket=true, outboundMessagesQueueSizeMetric=o.a.i.i.processors.metric.impl.LongAdderMetric@63a61cb2, super=GridNioSessionImpl [locAddr=/127.0.0.1:10800, rmtAddr=/127.0.0.1:60448, createTime=1723040891321, closeTime=0, bytesSent=2097792741, bytesRcvd=3762636511, bytesSent0=314590648, bytesRcvd0=599030499, sndSchedTime=1723577220281, lastSndTime=1723577220281, lastRcvTime=1723577220281, readsPaused=false, filterChain=FilterChain[filters=[GridNioAsyncNotifyFilter, GridNioCodecFilter [parser=ClientListenerNioMessageParser, directMode=true], SSL filter], accepted=true, markedForClose=false]]]
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.throwConnectionReset(SocketChannelImpl.java:394)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:426)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$DirectNioClientWorker.processRead(GridNioServer.java:1351)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$AbstractNioClientWorker.processSelectedKeysOptimized(GridNioServer.java:2526)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$AbstractNioClientWorker.bodyInternal(GridNioServer.java:2281)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$AbstractNioClientWorker.body(GridNioServer.java:1910)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:125)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
[00:57:03,298][WARNING][grid-nio-worker-client-listener-1-#42][ClientListenerProcessor] Client disconnected abruptly due to network connection loss or because the connection was left open on application shutdown. [cls=class o.a.i.i.util.nio.GridNioException, msg=Connection reset]
[00:57:03,298][WARNING][grid-nio-worker-client-listener-0-#41][ClientListenerProcessor] Client disconnected abruptly due to network connection loss or because the connection was left open on application shutdown. [cls=class o.a.i.i.util.nio.GridNioException, msg=Connection reset]
[00:57:04,302][SEVERE][grid-nio-worker-client-listener-1-#42][ClientListenerProcessor] Failed to process selector key [ses=GridSelectorNioSessionImpl [worker=DirectNioClientWorker [super=AbstractNioClientWorker [idx=1, bytesRcvd=379299492, bytesSent=0, bytesRcvd0=489020, bytesSent0=0, select=true, super=GridWorker [name=grid-nio-worker-client-listener-1, igniteInstanceName=null, finished=false, heartbeatTs=1723577223293, hashCode=946306202, interrupted=false, runner=grid-nio-worker-client-listener-1-#42]]], writeBuf=java.nio.DirectByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=65536 cap=65536], readBuf=java.nio.DirectByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=65536 cap=65536], inRecovery=null, outRecovery=null, closeSocket=true, outboundMessagesQueueSizeMetric=o.a.i.i.processors.metric.impl.LongAdderMetric@63a61cb2, super=GridNioSessionImpl [locAddr=/127.0.0.1:10800, rmtAddr=/127.0.0.1:60395, createTime=1723038743588, closeTime=0, bytesSent=41859, bytesRcvd=1871341, bytesSent0=9718, bytesRcvd0=471210, sndSchedTime=1723577022537, lastSndTime=1723577022537, lastRcvTime=1723577022537, readsPaused=false, filterChain=FilterChain[filters=[GridNioAsyncNotifyFilter, GridNioCodecFilter [parser=ClientListenerNioMessageParser, directMode=true], SSL filter], accepted=true, markedForClose=false]]]
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.throwConnectionReset(SocketChannelImpl.java:394)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:426)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$DirectNioClientWorker.processRead(GridNioServer.java:1351)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$AbstractNioClientWorker.processSelectedKeysOptimized(GridNioServer.java:2526)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$AbstractNioClientWorker.bodyInternal(GridNioServer.java:2281)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$AbstractNioClientWorker.body(GridNioServer.java:1910)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:125)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
[00:57:04,302][WARNING][grid-nio-worker-client-listener-1-#42][ClientListenerProcessor] Client disconnected abruptly due to network connection loss or because the connection was left open on application shutdown. [cls=class o.a.i.i.util.nio.GridNioException, msg=Connection reset]
[00:57:13,951][INFO][grid-timeout-worker-#30][IgniteKernal] 
Metrics for local node (to disable set 'metricsLogFrequency' to 0)
    ^-- Node [id=4b92db2a, uptime=6 days, 05:42:58.029]
    ^-- Cluster [hosts=1, CPUs=12, servers=1, clients=0, topVer=1, minorTopVer=6]
    ^-- Network [addrs=[127.0.0.1], discoPort=8300, commPort=4321]
    ^-- CPU [CPUs=12, curLoad=0%, avgLoad=0%, GC=0%]
    ^-- Heap [used=989MB, free=83.9%, comm=3072MB]
    ^-- Outbound messages queue [size=0]
    ^-- Public thread pool [active=0, idle=0, qSize=0]
    ^-- System thread pool [active=0, idle=32, qSize=0]
    ^-- Striped thread pool [active=0, idle=12, qSize=0]
[00:57:13,952][INFO][grid-timeout-worker-#30][IgniteKernal] 
    ^--   sysMemPlc region [type=internal, persistence=true, lazyAlloc=false,
      ...  initCfg=40MB, maxCfg=100MB, usedRam=0MB, freeRam=99.98%, allocRam=99MB, allocTotal=0MB]
    ^--   metastoreMemPlc region [type=internal, persistence=true, lazyAlloc=false,
      ...  initCfg=40MB, maxCfg=100MB, usedRam=0MB, freeRam=99.94%, allocRam=0MB, allocTotal=0MB]
    ^--   TxLog region [type=internal, persistence=true, lazyAlloc=false,
      ...  initCfg=40MB, maxCfg=100MB, usedRam=0MB, freeRam=100%, allocRam=99MB, allocTotal=0MB]
    ^--   volatileDsMemPlc region [type=user, persistence=false, lazyAlloc=true,
      ...  initCfg=40MB, maxCfg=100MB, usedRam=0MB, freeRam=100%, allocRam=0MB]
    ^--   Default_Region region [type=default, persistence=true, lazyAlloc=true,
      ...  initCfg=256MB, maxCfg=409MB, usedRam=61MB, freeRam=84.87%, allocRam=409MB, allocTotal=61MB]

[00:57:13,952][INFO][grid-timeout-worker-#30][IgniteKernal] 

Data storage metrics for local node (to disable set 'metricsLogFrequency' to 0)
    ^-- Off-heap memory [used=62MB, free=92.34%, allocated=609MB]
    ^-- Page memory [pages=15702]
    ^-- Ignite persistence [used=62MB]

[00:57:44,758][INFO][shutdown-hook][G] Invoking shutdown hook...


Post Machine Restart:
After the machine rebooted, the Ignite cache attempted to start but failed to do so. The error details:
[01:00:35,703][SEVERE][main][IgniteKernal] Exception during start processors, node will be stopped and close connections
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: WAL history is too short [descs=[FileDescriptor [file=C:\Cache-Storage\db\wal\archive\node00-fa5c1be6-16b3-482d-a208-ba10adec9fca\0000000000000462.wal, idx=462], FileDescriptor [file=C:\Cache-Storage\db\wal\archive\node00-fa5c1be6-16b3-482d-a208-ba10adec9fca\0000000000000463.wal, idx=463], FileDescriptor [file=C:\Cache-Storage\db\wal\archive\node00-fa5c1be6-16b3-482d-a208-ba10adec9fca\0000000000000464.wal, idx=464], FileDescriptor [file=C:\Cache-Storage\db\wal\archive\node00-fa5c1be6-16b3-482d-a208-ba10adec9fca\0000000000000465.wal, idx=465], FileDescriptor [file=C:\Cache-Storage\db\wal\archive\node00-fa5c1be6-16b3-482d-a208-ba10adec9fca\0000000000000466.wal, idx=466], FileDescriptor [file=C:\Cache-Storage\db\wal\archive\node00-fa5c1be6-16b3-482d-a208-ba10adec9fca\0000000000000467.wal, idx=467], FileDescriptor [file=C:\Cache-Storage\db\wal\archive\node00-fa5c1be6-16b3-482d-a208-ba10adec9fca\0000000000000468.wal, idx=468], FileDescriptor [file=C:\Cache-Storage\db\wal\archive\node00-fa5c1be6-16b3-482d-a208-ba10adec9fca\0000000000000469.wal, idx=469]], start=WALPointer [idx=396, fileOff=54785709, len=50617]]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.wal.FileWriteAheadLogManager$RecordsIterator.init(FileWriteAheadLogManager.java:3039)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.wal.FileWriteAheadLogManager$RecordsIterator.access$1000(FileWriteAheadLogManager.java:2911)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.wal.FileWriteAheadLogManager.replay(FileWriteAheadLogManager.java:1082)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.wal.FileWriteAheadLogManager.replay(FileWriteAheadLogManager.java:1049)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.wal.FileWriteAheadLogManager.read(FileWriteAheadLogManager.java:1037)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager.performBinaryMemoryRestore(GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager.java:2119)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager.readMetastore(GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager.java:865)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager.notifyMetaStorageSubscribersOnReadyForRead(GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager.java:3094)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.start(IgniteKernal.java:1120)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1725)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start(IgnitionEx.java:1647)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1089)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:599)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.PlatformAbstractBootstrap.start(PlatformAbstractBootstrap.java:43)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.PlatformIgnition.start(PlatformIgnition.java:74)

The only solution I found was to delete the "Cache-Storage" folder (referenced in the error details below) and restart the Ignite cache, after which it functioned correctly.
Any help in resolving this issue will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
Windows updates:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/august-13-2024-kb5041580-os-builds-19044-4780-and-19045-4780-2ef55b0d-bb01-41c8-8629-4146929792ad
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/august-13-2024-kb5042352-cumulative-update-for-net-framework-3-5-4-8-and-4-8-1-for-windows-10-version-22h2-4716cff5-6c43-4d1b-a4c3-4b517fa8898a

As suggested in The ignite docker keeps restarting automatically. Error cause :IgniteCheckedException: WAL history is too short, you might try to switch to
FSYNC for WAL_MODE, which should help to survive OS crashes, but can also affect performance in some way. Besides, running a multi-node cluster with backup factor greater than 0 would also add stability to your setup.
